# Davening near a cemetery

Tags: tefilla, blessing, cemetery-grave

As suggested by DoubleAA on [this similar but more unusual question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/96087/11532).

If you go to a cemetery and haven't been to one recently, you say a bracha:

> ברוך אתה ה' אלקינו מלך העולם אשר יצר אתכם בדין וזן אתכם בדין וכלכל אתכם בדין והמית אתכם בדין ויודע מספר כולכם והוא עתיד להחיותכם ולקים אתכם בדין. ברוך אתה ה' מחיה המתים. ‏

This bracha ends the same way as the second bracha in Shemoneh Esrei.  If you daven near a cemetery, does one in Shemoneh Esrei count for both?  Should it be modified in any way to reference the deceased people in the cemetery you're standing in?

Comment: The Pri Megadim thinks you can't say Elohai Neshama after Shacharit for this reason. Your case would seem to be a Kol Shekein (though his base position is disputable)