# Eating with a plate that had non-kosher food on it at one point in the past

Tags: kashrut-kosher, baal-teshuva, glass

In light of this quarantine, If someone is spending shabbat at non-observant relatives and the house is not kosher. If the person runs out of paper plates, would he be able to eat from a glass plate that had had non-kosher food on it at one point in the past as long as it was thoroughly washed so there are no visible stains (which is permissible unless I am mistaken according to Sephardic authorities).

Note that this assumes that the person was unable to run to the store to buy new paper plates.

Comment: A number of kashrut agencies have guidance on the web (e.g., OU, StarK, CRC) and talk about such topics. Look for terms such as hot, cold, sharp, ben-yomo, ano ben-yomo. For example, https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/term-aino-ben-yomo-mean/

Comment: Why close this question and not close some questions you yourself asked, e.g.: 
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106956/outdoor-prayer-facing-rainbow 
- Should they face the wrong direction? Proceed as usual? Delay?  
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65628/minimum-amount-of-food-for-beracha-rishona  
- How much would one need to eat in order to say a Beracha Rishona  
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14213/tevilat-keilim-on-a-gift 
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16513/can-a-woman-drink-the-kos-shel-bracha

Comment: Agreed. This question is a great question and has a lot of potential for answers. I agree with @YehudaW that this should be reopened.